# How to alter a table in SQLite after running a pragma

Tags: sqlite

I am attempting to check a database that already exist and querying through a table to see how many columns it has by calling this.

```
    if(res.toString().contains('Orchestration_Time')){
      await _database.execute('PRAGMA table_info(Orchestration_Time)'
    );
```

after this bit of code runs I need a way to use the information I get back to then determine if I should alter the table or not

```
'ALTER TABLE Orchestration_Time ADD COLUMN dashboard_area TEXT;'
```

but I cannot figure out how to access the data that the PRAGMA statement returns.

I'd like to wrap it in an 'if' statement and run the alter table if the PRAGMA is less than 5.

Comment: The same way you access rows returned by a select, however that's done in whatever language you're using.

Comment: @Shawn ah, I have the PRAGMA call in an .execute, instead of a rawQuery which is why i was unable to access the information, since an .execute returns a void.